# Cannot compile mediapipe via Mac OS on Android

Tags: android, bazel, mediapipe

I'm trying to build mediapipe project for the first time, reading through https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/android.html, and can't get bazel to complete successfully, so far using Option 1.

Based on the error, the file `dx.jar` is missing from `/private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/4a399cb8dd247974fabba333258e1f5f/external/androidsdk/build-tools/31.0.0-rc5/lib` folder (below). Could the file name have changed to d8.jar?

```
-rw-r--r--   1 ted  staff   965K Jun 10 12:54 apksigner.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 ted  staff   5.8M Jun 10 12:54 d8.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 ted  staff    28K Jun 10 12:54 shrinkedAndroid.jar
```

I prefer to use Android Studio (Option 2) but my separate build with it failed also.

If I've left out any information that can help identify the problem, please let me know. Thank you.

Versions

- bazel 4.1.0-homebrew
- Python 3.9.5
- MacOS Big Sur 11.4
- ANDROID_HOME = /Users/ted/Library/Android/sdk
- ANDROID_NDK_HOME = /Users/ted/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529
- JAVA_HOME = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

Output

```
% bazel build -c opt --config=android_arm64 mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_absl' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_protobuf' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_googletest' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_github_gflags_gflags' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_apple' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_swift' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_apple_support' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'bazel_skylib' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'pybind11' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/tf_runtime/third_party/cuda/dependencies.bzl:51:10: The following command will download NVIDIA proprietary software. By using the software you agree to comply with the terms of the license agreement that accompanies the software. If you do not agree to the terms of the license agreement, do not use the software.
INFO: Analyzed target //mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu (179 packages loaded, 16257 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/collection_has_min_size_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/rect_to_render_data_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/annotation_overlay_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/detections_to_render_data_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/constant_side_packet_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tflite/ssd_anchors_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/split_vector_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/flow_limiter_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/labels_to_render_data_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/landmark_projection_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/non_max_suppression_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tflite/tflite_custom_op_resolver_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/detections_to_rects_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tflite/tflite_custom_op_resolver_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/internal/callback_packet_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/framework/tool/calculator_graph_template.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/gpu/gl_context_options.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/framework/calculator_profile.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/landmarks_to_render_data_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tflite/ssd_anchors_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/tensors_to_landmarks_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/tensors_to_classification_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/tensors_to_floats_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:13:25: Extracting interface @androidsdk//:dx_jar_import failed: missing input file 'external/androidsdk/build-tools/31.0.0-rc5/lib/dx.jar', owner: '@androidsdk//:build-tools/31.0.0-rc5/lib/dx.jar'
Target //mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:13:25 Extracting interface @androidsdk//:dx_jar_import failed: 1 input file(s) do not exist
INFO: Elapsed time: 22.063s, Critical Path: 12.97s
INFO: 364 processes: 192 internal, 172 darwin-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
579 mediapipe1 (master) > rehash
580 mediapipe1 (master) > bazel build -c opt --config=android_arm64 mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_absl' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_protobuf' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_googletest' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_github_gflags_gflags' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_apple' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_swift' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_apple_support' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'bazel_skylib' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:108:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'pybind11' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/tf_runtime/third_party/cuda/dependencies.bzl:51:10: The following command will download NVIDIA proprietary software. By using the software you agree to comply with the terms of the license agreement that accompanies the software. If you do not agree to the terms of the license agreement, do not use the software.
INFO: Analyzed target //mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/thresholding_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/tensors_to_landmarks_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/image_to_tensor_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/thresholding_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/gate_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/tensors_to_floats_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/image_to_tensor_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/inference_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/split_vector_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/framework/calculator_profile.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/tensors_to_classification_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/clip_vector_size_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/inference_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/rect_transformation_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/framework/tool/calculator_graph_template.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/internal/callback_packet_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/clip_vector_size_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/constant_side_packet_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/tensors_to_detections_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/association_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/flow_limiter_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/collection_has_min_size_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/non_max_suppression_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/landmark_projection_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/tensor/tensors_to_detections_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/rect_transformation_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/gpu/gl_context_options.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/detections_to_render_data_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/annotation_overlay_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/labels_to_render_data_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/landmarks_to_render_data_calculator.pb.h [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/gpu/gl_surface_sink_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/association_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/detections_to_rects_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/core/gate_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From ProtoCompile mediapipe/calculators/util/rect_to_render_data_calculator.pb.h:
bazel-out/android-arm64-v8a-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src: warning: directory does not exist.
INFO: From Compiling mediapipe/framework/tool/text_to_binary_graph.cc [for host]:
In file included from mediapipe/framework/tool/text_to_binary_graph.cc:27:
In file included from ./mediapipe/framework/port/ret_check.h:18:
In file included from ./mediapipe/framework/deps/ret_check.h:19:
./mediapipe/framework/deps/status_builder.h:77:12: warning: 'Status' is deprecated: Use absl::Status directly [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  operator Status() const&;
           ^
./mediapipe/framework/deps/status.h:30:14: note: 'Status' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
using Status ABSL_DEPRECATED("Use absl::Status directly") = absl::Status;
             ^
external/com_google_absl/absl/base/attributes.h:649:49: note: expanded from macro 'ABSL_DEPRECATED'
#define ABSL_DEPRECATED(message) __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                                                ^
In file included from mediapipe/framework/tool/text_to_binary_graph.cc:27:
In file included from ./mediapipe/framework/port/ret_check.h:18:
In file included from ./mediapipe/framework/deps/ret_check.h:19:
./mediapipe/framework/deps/status_builder.h:78:12: warning: 'Status' is deprecated: Use absl::Status directly [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  operator Status() &&;
           ^
./mediapipe/framework/deps/status.h:30:14: note: 'Status' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
using Status ABSL_DEPRECATED("Use absl::Status directly") = absl::Status;
             ^
external/com_google_absl/absl/base/attributes.h:649:49: note: expanded from macro 'ABSL_DEPRECATED'
#define ABSL_DEPRECATED(message) __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                                                ^
2 warnings generated.
INFO: From Building external/com_google_protobuf/libprotobuf_javalite.jar (86 source files):
warning: -parameters is not supported for target value 1.7. Use 1.8 or later.
INFO: From Compiling mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc [for host]:
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc:1714:13: warning: 'enable_input_output_latency' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (this->enable_input_output_latency() != 0) {
            ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:1016:3: note: 'enable_input_output_latency' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED bool enable_input_output_latency() const;
  ^
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:151:44: note: expanded from macro 'PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED'
#define PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc:1781:13: warning: 'trace_log_duration_events' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (this->trace_log_duration_events() != 0) {
            ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:1097:3: note: 'trace_log_duration_events' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED bool trace_log_duration_events() const;
  ^
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:151:44: note: expanded from macro 'PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED'
#define PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc:1863:13: warning: 'enable_input_output_latency' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (this->enable_input_output_latency() != 0) {
            ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:1016:3: note: 'enable_input_output_latency' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED bool enable_input_output_latency() const;
  ^
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:151:44: note: expanded from macro 'PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED'
#define PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc:1918:13: warning: 'trace_log_duration_events' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (this->trace_log_duration_events() != 0) {
            ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:1097:3: note: 'trace_log_duration_events' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED bool trace_log_duration_events() const;
  ^
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:151:44: note: expanded from macro 'PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED'
#define PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc:1979:12: warning: 'enable_input_output_latency' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (from.enable_input_output_latency() != 0) {
           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:1016:3: note: 'enable_input_output_latency' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED bool enable_input_output_latency() const;
  ^
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:151:44: note: expanded from macro 'PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED'
#define PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc:2006:12: warning: 'trace_log_duration_events' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (from.trace_log_duration_events() != 0) {
           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:1097:3: note: 'trace_log_duration_events' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED bool trace_log_duration_events() const;
  ^
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:151:44: note: expanded from macro 'PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED'
#define PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc:2575:13: warning: 'has_profiler_config' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (this->has_profiler_config()) {
            ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:1533:3: note: 'has_profiler_config' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED bool has_profiler_config() const;
  ^
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:151:44: note: expanded from macro 'PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED'
#define PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc:2711:13: warning: 'has_profiler_config' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (this->has_profiler_config()) {
            ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:1533:3: note: 'has_profiler_config' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED bool has_profiler_config() const;
  ^
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:151:44: note: expanded from macro 'PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED'
#define PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.cc:2797:12: warning: 'has_profiler_config' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (from.has_profiler_config()) {
           ^
bazel-out/host/bin/mediapipe/framework/calculator.pb.h:1533:3: note: 'has_profiler_config' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED bool has_profiler_config() const;
  ^
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc:151:44: note: expanded from macro 'PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED'
#define PROTOBUF_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                           ^
9 warnings generated.
INFO: From Executing genrule //mediapipe/modules/palm_detection:palm_detection_gpu_graph:
[libprotobuf WARNING external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:324] Warning parsing text-format mediapipe.CalculatorGraphConfig: 60:5: text format contains deprecated field "use_gpu"
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:13:25: Extracting interface @androidsdk//:dx_jar_import failed: missing input file 'external/androidsdk/build-tools/31.0.0-rc5/lib/dx.jar', owner: '@androidsdk//:build-tools/31.0.0-rc5/lib/dx.jar'
Target //mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/handtrackinggpu:handtrackinggpu failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ted/a2941b1f43fe20e22cb2ef5eec9c5c26/external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:13:25 Extracting interface @androidsdk//:dx_jar_import failed: 1 input file(s) do not exist
INFO: Elapsed time: 2553.448s, Critical Path: 1262.11s
INFO: 3236 processes: 120 internal, 3101 darwin-sandbox, 15 worker.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem was using Android SDK build tools version 31.0.0-rc5 which does not include the `dx.jar` file for some reason. I removed this version and used the latest stable version 30.0.3 and compilation completed successfully.

Answer (score 4):

as @Jackpile said: to do that you need to change WORKSPACE, you probably you just need to update the sdk call to this:

```
android_sdk_repository(name = "androidsdk", build_tools_version = "30.0.3")
```